# Assign javascript array to style another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Might be a question with a simple answer, but I can't find it.

Is there a simpler way to do this:

```
$('#' + array_with_ID[0]).css('width', array_with_px_value[0] + 'px');
$('#' + array_with_ID[1]).css('width', array_with_px_value[1] + 'px');
$('#' + array_with_ID[2]).css('width', array_with_px_value[2] + 'px');
$('#' + array_with_ID[3]).css('width', array_with_px_value[3] + 'px');
$('#' + array_with_ID[4]).css('width', array_with_px_value[4] + 'px');
etc...
```

Comment: Could you show us your array?

Comment: a for-loop might help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ( var i = 0, l = Math.max(array_with_ID.length, array_with_px_value.length); i < l; ++i ) {
    $('#' + array_with_ID[i]).css('width', array_with_px_value[i] + 'px');
}
```

Something like this should help. You don't even need the `Math.max` if you know they will always be the same length.

Comment: Pretty much what I was about to post; but you should probably have `.length` at the end of both of those Math.max arguments, right?

Comment: @Katana314 saw that while I was adding the description. Would definitely have produced bad results...

Comment: Trouble with using arrays of different lengths is that I'm pretty sure an exception will happen if it can't find the element at that position? `Math.min` might be a better option?

Comment: @Darkzaelus It won't give an exception, it will just be `undefined`.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I'm out of touch with javascript! I should take my own advice and try it out before I go mad with my mouth

Comment: Works like a charm! Awesome

Answer (score 0):

```
var array_with_ID = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4', 'div5', 'div6', 'div7'];
var array_with_px_value = [ 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270 ];

$(array_with_ID).each(function(i){
    $('#' + this).css('width', array_with_px_value[i] + 'px');
});
```

jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will loop through arrays.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/6PFpf/1/)